# Is there a constructive proof that a Euclidean domain is a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

The proof (at least the proof I know) that a principal ideal domain is a unique factorization domain uses the axiom of choice in multiple ways, and the usual way to show that a Euclidean domain is a UFD is to show that it's a PID (which is easy and constructive).

Is there a direct proof, not using the axiom of choice, that a Euclidean domain is a UFD?

Comment: Whoops, misread the question, yes.

Comment: Having received no answers here, I'm trying on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255239/is-there-a-choice-free-proof-that-a-euclidean-domain-is-a-ufd